# Why main.jsbundle.map is impacted by resources?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a vague understanding of how `main.jsbundle.map` works and why it's needed. As I got it so far - it is used to have a mapping between the minified code and original one.

I'm trying to upload the file to [Sentry](https://sentry.io) and getting an error that it's too big. After further investigation, I can see, that the size is impacted by the resources folder size. The question - Why does the file should know about images? Is it possible to tell react native not to put the images data inside?

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail about how the main.jsbundle.map is being produced.